# Does changing image channel break the image?

Tags: image, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

so I have images with the format(width,height,channel). My original channel is in rgb. So I Load the images in grayscale

```
for r, d, file in tqdm(os.walk(path)):
  for i in tqdm(file):
    if i[0:2]=="01":
      dist_one.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,i),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
    else:
      dist_two.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,i),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

Suppose the images have the shape (187, 187). So I add a channel using the code

```
g = np.expand_dims(dist_one[0], axis=0)
```

But this breaks the images when I try to plot the image.

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()       1 import
>   matplotlib.pyplot as plt       2  ----> 3
>   plt.imshow(dist_one[0],cmap='gray')       4 plt.show()  5
>   frames/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in
>   set_data(self, A)     688                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and
>   self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):     689             raise
>   TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data" --> 690
>   .format(self._A.shape))     691      692 if self._A.ndim == 3: 
>   TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 187, 187) for image data

But it works when the channel is put last. 
`g = np.expand_dims(dist_one[0], axis=-1).` 
Whats the reason for this?
I need the channel at the first for pytorch. Or am I suppose to train the model with broken images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytorch requires [C, H, W], whereas numpy and matplotlib (which is where the error is being thrown) require the image to be [H, W, C]. To fix this issue, I'd suggest plotting g obtained by doing this `g = np.expand_dims(dist_one[0], axis=-1)`. Before sending it to PyTorch, you can do one of two things. You can use 'g = torch.tensor(g).permute(2, 0, 1)` which will results in a [C, H, W] tensor or you can use the PyTorch Dataset and Dataloader setup, which handles other things like batching for you.